Pyenv - Switching between Python and PySpark versions without hardcoding environment variable paths for python
I have trouble getting different versions of PySpark to work correctly on my windows machine in combination with different versions of Python installed via PyEnv.
The setup:

I installed pyenv and let it set the environment variables (PYENV, PYENV_HOME, PYENV_ROOT and the entry in PATH)
I installed Amazon Coretto Java JDK (jdk1.8.0_412) and set the JAVA_HOME environment variable.
I downloaded the winutils.exe & hadoop.dll from here and set the HADOOP_HOME environment variable.
Via pyenv I installed Python 3.10.10 and then pyspark 3.4.1
Via pyenv I installed Python 3.8.10 and then pyspark 3.2.1

Python works as expected:

I can switch between different versions with pyenv global <version>
When I use python --version in PowerShell it always shows the version that I set before with pyenv.

But I'm having trouble with PySpark.
For one, I cannot start PySpark via the powershell console by running pyspark >>> The term 'pyspark' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file.....
More annoyingly, my repo-scripts (with a .venv created via pyenv & poetry) also fail:

Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "python3": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified [...] Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

However, both work after I add the following two entries to the PATH environment variable:

C:\Users\myuser\.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.10.10
C:\Users\myuser\.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.10.10\Scripts

but I would have to "hardcode" the Python Version - which is exactly what I don't want to do while using pyenv.
If I hardcode the path, even if I switch to another Python version (pyenv global 3.8.10), once I run pyspark in Powershell, the version PySpark 3.4.1 starts from the environment PATH entry for Python 3.10.10. I also cannot just do anything with python in the command line as it always points to the hardcoded python version, no matter what I do with pyenv.
I was hoping to be able to start PySpark 3.2.1 from Python 3.8.10 which I just "activated" with pyenv globally.
What do I have to do to be able to switch between the Python installations (and thus also between PySparks) with pyenv without "hardcoding" the Python paths?
Example PySpark script:
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = (
    SparkSession
    .builder
    .master("local[*]")
    .appName("myapp")
    .getOrCreate()
)
data = [("Finance", 10),
        ("Marketing", 20),
        ]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data)
df.show(10, False)


have you tried using seperate virtual envs for pysprk versions? u can use something like pyenv-virtualenv

Sure, i use virtualenv and poetry even creates separate ones for different repositories. But that's not the issue here - the issue is that windows cannot call on the python / pyspark versions dynamically set by pyenv, instead I have to hardcode the environment variables to a specific versions.

I "solved" the issue by completely removing the Python path from the PATH environment variable and doing everything exclusively via pyenv. I suppose my original task is not possible.
I can still start a Python process by running pyenv exec python in the terminal.
But disappointingly I cannot launch a Spark process from the terminal anymore.
At least my repositories work as expected when setting the pyenv versions (pyenv local 3.8.10 / pyenv global 3.10.10).
